Algorithm For Largest Square-Free Divisor (a.k.a. Radical) Of An Integer
What is a fast algorithm to obtain the largest square-free divisor of a 64 bit unsigned integer. Can it be done without requiring full factorization?
radical(n) = prod_{p prime | n} p


I tackled this problem the following way. For larger numbers than 64 bit, probabalistic integer factorization algorithms faster than trial division by primes are probably going to be faster, but I used trial division by primes up to the cube root, so time complexity <= O(cbrt(n)). With some pre-computation for each of the first ~200k primes, the divisibility check can be performed using a multiplication which is quite a bit faster on most of today's hardware than using modulus or division. I expect this approach to be hard to beat in performance for 64 bit integers because of the simplicity of calculation of each divisibility check. My approach in pseudocode is described below. The functions isqrt() and icbrt() round down to the nearest integer.
  function radical(n)
    rad = 1
    p = 2
    isqrtn = isqrt(n)   
    while (n == (isqrtn*isqrtn)) 
      n = isqrtn
      isqrtn = isqrt(n)
    icbrtn = icbrt(n)
    while (p <= icbrtn)
      if (p | n)      
        n /= p
        rad *= p
        while (n % p == 0) n /= p
        if (n == 1) return rad
        isqrtn = isqrt(n) 
        while (n == (isqrtn*isqrtn)) 
          n = isqrtn
          isqrtn = isqrt(n) 
        icbrtn = icbrt(n)
      p = nextprime(p)
    return rad*n

The main idea is that if you know that n is not square and does not have a prime divisor <= icbrt(n) then it must be a prime or the product of two distinct primes. You don't need to know if n is prime or what its two prime factors are in this case to obtain the radical allowing it to exit after the cube root. My c coded function can be found here https://github.com/FastAsChuff/Fast-Square-Free-Integer-Functions.
If you know more information, then sometimes the radical can be calculated more efficiently. If you know non-trivial factors of n = pq then you can calculate the radical using the following equation.
radical(n) = radical(p)*radical(q) / gcd(radical(p), radical(q))

If you know the greatest square divisor s of n, then a more efficient method of obtaining the radical of n is as the pseudo-code below.
function radicalfromgsd(n, s)
  isqrtgsd = isqrt(s)
  radsqrtgsd = radical(isqrtgsd)
  v = n
  u = 2
  while (u > 1)
    u = gcd(v, radsqrtgsd)
    v /= u
  return v*radsqrtgsd

The only potentially challenging part is radical(isqrtgsd), but since isqrtgsd <= isqrt(n), it should be considerably faster to compute than radical(n).

Please add an explanation of what the parts of the code do, for example. what is the purpose of the while (n == (isqrtn*isqrtn)) loop? Also, you mention "some pre-computation for each of the first ~200k primes" - is that a given list of the first ~200k primes? Why 200k?

That loop just keeps taking the square root if n is square. The radical of an integer is the same as the radical of its square. The first 200k primes are sufficient to get to the cube root of any 64 bit unsigned integer.
